# ng-class is not working inside file included by ng-include in angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am loading menu using `ng-include` from index file,

```
<span ng-include="'app/components/common/menu.html'"></span>
```

menu.html is,

```
<li ng-class="active" >
        <a href="#/items"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-list"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Items</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#/clients"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-group"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Clients</span></a>
    </li>
```

here normal class,which is second one,working fine.But first one,`ng-class='active'` is not working,Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-class` must contain expression.

Using `ng-class="active"` you must define `$scope.active = 'yout_class'`.

If you need just `active` string, use `class="active"`.

Use `ng-class` for dinamically generated classes:

```
<div ng-class="{active: divShouldBeActive()}"></div>
```

Where `divShouldBeActive()` is your `$scope` function

Comment: if I am using $scope.active, it is working,so how can I write it for generally?

Comment: I guess you need to mark active menu item. Simple code sample:
    `<ul>
      <li ng-class="{active: menuItem.id == currentMenuId}" ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">menuItem.name</li>
   </ul>`
Where `menuItems` - array of items with {id:...,name:...} and `currentMenuId` is your current menu item id

Comment: Thank you,one more,How can I put or condition here `<li ng-class="{active: menuItem.id == currentMenuId}" `

Comment: You can use it like I've written. But I've just misspelled (missed quotes for 'active' string):
`<li ng-class="{'active': menuItem.id == currentMenuId}"....`